# PHP/Htaccess url redirect/mapping

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

I would like to have a mechanism where urls like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/x
```

Where 'x' is a number e.g

```
http://mywebsite.com/23
```

Will redirect to :

```
http://mywebsite.com/store.php?id=23
```

So if it should check if x is numeric. If it is, it should redirect to :

```
http://mywebsite.com/store.php?id=x
```

What should I use? Is there a way PHP does this natively?

I'm gussing I have to use Htaccess but the rules I make keep breaking apache so I have just sought to undo them all and seek counsel.

Comment: You do want to use rewrites for this. Please show your current `.htaccess` rules, and indicate how they "keep breaking Apache".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `but the rules I make keep breaking apache`

**Make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled when you try these rules.**

Place this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /store.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```